Why Do Some American Universities Prefer Direct PhD Programs Over Master's for International Students?
In exploring graduate programs in the United States, I've noticed a trend where several universities offer fewer Master's programs for international students and instead have a larger number of direct PhD programs available after undergraduate studies. This seems particularly prevalent in fields like science and engineering. I'm curious about the reasons behind this educational structure.

What advantages do universities see in promoting direct PhD admissions over a separate Master's track for international students?
Does this model benefit the universities in terms of funding, research output, or global rankings?
How does this impact the career trajectories of international students who might traditionally benefit from a Master's degree before committing to a PhD?


I have never heard of a "master's for international students." In what fields/countries is it common to offer a master's specifically for international students? What makes them ill-suited to master's programs for US citizens?

@AzorAhai-him- I think you misunderstood the question.

Not sure how else to read "several universities offer fewer Master's programs for international students" / "promoting direct PhD admissions over a separate Master's track for international students?"

A number of highly-rated engineering schools happily accept masters students - for an engineer in industry the masters is a fine terminal degree. On the other hand, some departments may focus on PhDs only, and use the masters as an exit point.

I'm not understanding the "for international students" parts of your question; can't I just delete those three words wherever they appear and have the same question? What are you seeing as specific for international students? Where are you seeing programs for international students specifically rather than all students?

Separately, when you say "few Master's programs" and "larger number", then what are you comparing to? A historical number from the past? Something else? I just don't understand what the question here actually is.

Actually, most doctoral programs in the US in most fields are open to those with only a bachelors. It isn't a few. It is nearly all. There are several reasons. Probably the most important, though perhaps not stated, is that the faculty gets to look at a student for a while before taking them on as a dissertation advisor. But there are many other considerations including how the university is managed overall.
Most programs start with advanced coursework giving a broad education in the field of interest. This leads to required comprehensive exams in the major subfields. Once past that, perhaps in the third year, serious research toward the dissertation begins. It may be that you earn a masters along the way, sometimes just for filling out paperwork and sometimes after a minor thesis. But this isn't necessary for everyone.
Most universities also have masters programs intended for those not interested in a doctorate, perhaps because they want industry positions, rather than an academic career. These are normally funded by the students themselves through tuition and fees. On the contrary, doctoral programs are normally funded differently through Teaching or Research Assistant positions, which normally include nearly all fees as well as a modest living stipend.
The advantage of the doctoral funding arrangement is that most major doctoral programs also have a large undergraduate population and the TAs help maintain the lower level courses by grading and by holding regular small group sessions for students whose courses might be very large (hundreds of students). They make some personal contact possible to ask questions and get feedback. Without TAs the faculty would need to be much larger, leading to a much different financing issue.
Note that my experience is Math and CS. In those fields, most entering doctoral students haven't gone to R1 (major research) institutions as undergraduates and actually have little significant research experience. This is due to a lot of factors, but the US undergraduate program is very broad with a math major taking courses in writing, history, philosophy (perhaps) and several others. There is little time, even in a four year program for research and few reach enough experience in their field to be able to do anything but poke a bit at research.
Even masters programs in the US, which are often just two years, are too short for most students to do serious, leading edge, research. Some masters programs are just advanced coursework, such as a beginning doctoral student might have, and some require a thesis. It isn't likely to be leading edge, however.
There are some exceptions, however. A few programs run closer to the German model where students are expected to have a masters on entry and are immediately assigned to a lab where they are given some "research adjacent" tasks that will hopefully lead to a doctorate. This isn't the norm, however.
Where a broad based education, validated by comprehensive exams, is the expectation someone who already has a masters might actually be at a disadvantage if their masters didn't provide that broad base making it possible to pass those exams, which can be very challenging and are normally based on advanced, not elementary, material.
I don't see a lot of relation between this model and global rankings. It is an alternative model that works. Funding of US research universities is very varied. Some is from the states that run the university. Some is from foundation grants. Some (a lot) is from tuition paid by students. But the TA system helps keep costs down due to the modest nature of the funding compared to the salary and benefits that need to be paid to research faculty along with the cost of facilities in general.
International students with bachelors are admissible to such programs on the same basis. Some might even have an advantage since the bachelors program in several places is more field-intense than is typical of a US bachelors. And with a masters you might still need to deal with comprehensive exams.

As a gross generality, the larger the department the more degree options there may be.
Choosing one large, well known, highly ranked program, the Electrical Engineering and Computer Science department at UC Berkeley. They offer:
A 5-year combined bachelor/masters described as:

This program is available only to Berkeley EECS and CS Undergraduates. It is a five year combined Bachelor/Master’s program geared toward outstanding and highly motivated students who desire a program of study that offers greater breadth than is practical in the B.S. or B.A. programs alone.

A Masters of Engineering described as:

The Master of Engineering is designed for students who plan to join the engineering profession following graduation. This accelerated program is designed to develop professional engineering leaders of the future who understand the technical, economic, and social issues of technology.

Graduate research degree programs:

The Master of Science (M.S.) and Doctor of Philosophy (Ph.D.) programs emphasize research preparation and experience.

although they also note:

The MS only degree is intended mostly for currently registered UC Berkeley Ph.D. students that want to add the degree. Occasionally we admit exceptional applicants with research experience, but the cohort generally is limited to less than 10. Students interested in a research oriented degree should consider applying directly to the MS/PhD program.

Further, UC Berkeley EECS also offers a combined PhD/MD program.
None of these programs are aimed solely at international students, nor have I seen such programs at the universities that I am familiar with.

In most STEM fields a masters is seen as a failed PhD. This is largely due to the fact that people who fail to advance beyond their quals (or equivalent) for their PhD are given the option of "mastering out" after completing basic course requirements, and sometimes a short research report (wouldn't even call it a true thesis).
Masters programs are mostly pedagogical in nature. In the US (at research active schools, even research active PUIs) there is a lot of emphasis on undergraduate research. So the need for a masters research class of students is low (we already have such a big pool of often quite talented undergrads). Whereas PhD students who can take on long-term research projects are much more valuable.
So unfortunately, a STEM masters is just stuck in the middle of two strong programs (research focused undergraduate, and PhD).

This doesn't match my experience at all, except for a few programs.
